# Creating temporary URL link in Opera browser

Tags: cross-browser, opera

**window.url.createobjecturl()** doesn't work in opera! I want to link a video file to html5 'video' tag which i selected via 'input file' html tag. I'm able to link the video in Chrome, Firefox, IE10 using **window.url.createobjecturl()**. So is there any snippet which i can use to solve this problem. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet:

```
    if(navigator.getUserMedia){
        if(!window.URL) window.URL = {};
        if(!window.URL.createObjectURL) window.URL.createObjectURL = function(obj){return obj;};
    }
```